# generating a number of divs at a time in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to make a game with jquery where bullets are appended using a function. So far bullets are generating whenever I press spacebar but I want to generate bullets like 3-5 stacks. 3-5 bullets will be generated and then a short break then again 3-5 bullets will be generated and the process continues. Bullets are appended as `div` element. Here are the codes,

```
function generateBullet() {
var Player = $('#player');
var PlayerLeft = Player.offset().left;
var PlayerTop = Player.offset().top - 50;
var appendingValue = "<div class='bulletID' style=' position: absolute; left: 250px; top: 250px;'></div>";
var appendSize = $('.bulletID').size();
if (appendSize >= 3) {
    $('#content').delay(5000).append(appendingValue);
} else {
    $('#content').append(appendingValue);
 }
}

function animateBullet() {
var bulletID = $('.bulletID');
bulletID.each(function () {
    var nowTop = $(this).offset().top;
    $(this).css("top", nowTop - 25);
 });
}

var keys = {}
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
delete keys[e.keyCode];
});

function shoot() {
var Player = $('#player');
for (var direction in keys) {
    if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(direction)) continue;
    if (direction == 32) {
        generateBullet();
    }
 }
}
```

**JSFIDDLE DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/ygz5wo7r/1/

I'm not getting any more idea how to do this. Your help will be really appreciated. TnQ.

Comment: id's should be unique `$('#bulletID')` only returns 1st one

Comment: @andrew, Updated jsfiddle. Plz chk again!

Comment: 3-5 bullets will be generated on a space press or 3-5 bullets will be generated maximum on space hold and then a short break

Comment: @iceless, 3-5 bullets will be generated maximum on space hold and then a short break.

Comment: why not count how many you shoot and when counter reaches 5, reset and skip next bullet...

Comment: By the way consider looking at the HTML5 canvas for that sort of games. It's a lot better, runs smoother and it's lighter than manipulating the DOM with jQuery. You can find a lot of examples through the internet :)) Good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/naz1bav6/)**

I added

```
return false;
```

after

```
if (appendSize >= 3) {
  ...
```

and

```
parseInt($(this).css("top"))< 0 && $(this).remove();
```

to `animateBullet()`

to remove the bullets when they leave the screen

Comment: yes thats exactly what I was looking for. Tnx a lot bro. I'm so noob in jquery.

Comment: thats ok `var appendSize = $('.bulletID').size();` will get the number of bullets, but you needed to remove the elements

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. Because you don't have control over the duration in which you can't shoot. You have to wait until the bullets go to the end of screen and disappear so that you can fire again.

Comment: @iceless it is a quick and dirty solution, but you could change the `0` in `parseInt($(this).css("top"))< 0` if you want the bullets to get destroyed earlier

Comment: If your player is moving it's hard to implement and not a good practice I think

Answer (score 2):

you can count how many bullets you fired each chain, and block the gun if chain reaches 3-5 bullets. and then using a timeout you can unblock the gun. that way you have control over the interval between bullet chains:

**<kbd>[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygz5wo7r/6/)</kbd>**

```
var bullets_chain = 0;
var block_gun = false;

function generateBullet() {

    if (block_gun == false) {
        var Player = $('#player');
        var PlayerLeft = Player.offset().left;
        var PlayerTop = Player.offset().top - 50;
        var appendingValue = "<div class='bulletID' style=' position: absolute; left: 250px; top: 250px;'></div>";
        bullets_chain++;
        if (bullets_chain >= 5) {
            block_gun = true;
            bullets_chain = 0;
            setTimeout(function () {
                block_gun = false;
            }, 500);
        }
        $('#content').append(appendingValue);
    }
}

function animateBullet() {
    var bulletID = $('.bulletID');
    bulletID.each(function () {
        var nowTop = $(this).offset().top;
        if (nowTop < 0) {
            $(this).remove();
        } else {

            $(this).css("top", nowTop - 25);
        }
    });
}

var keys = {}
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (block_gun == false) {
        keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    }
});

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
});

function shoot() {
    var Player = $('#player');
    for (var direction in keys) {
        if (!keys.hasOwnProperty(direction)) continue;
        if (direction == 32) {
            generateBullet();
        }
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(shoot, 50);
    setInterval(animateBullet, 100);
});
```

Comment: +1 now that's what I was thinking about but you implemented it faster :D. Just need to add the bullet removal.